# Ubuntu 12.10 installation options

Tags: installation, 12.10, partitioning

I got a 400 GB hard disk with 200 GB allocated to windows vista and 200 GB unpartitioned space. During the installation I selected "Install ubuntu alongside windows vista". Then I clicked on Install now but I was not given the choice of choosing the size of /, swap and home partitions. Are the sizes automatically chosen for you? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Install ubuntu alongside windows vista` try `do something else`. That will hopefully provide the option for choosing the size of /, swap and home partitions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, "install alongside *" is an automated installation option and the sizes are chosen for you. As @REGZEN said, if you want to control the way your HD is partitioned choose "do something else".